# Multiplying the values in one columns by values in other columns by ignoring zero in pandas without hard cording it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to multiply values in a columns by values in other columns.
I normally multiply the values using by specifying the column using following formula in pandas
e.g. `dataframe.column1 * dataframe.column2`.

Here is the example `DataFrame`:

[image]

I want to multiply values as follows:

- `PRO_RATE`  X  `DEF_POINT2`

(continue to other columns such as DEF_POINT3, DEF_POINT4 etc..)
each of the above columns have `nan` values, which I do not want to multiply with values in `PRO_RATE` columns.

Expected Result:

[image]

Sample `DataFrame`:

```
data = {'PRO_RATE':[.5,.3,.6,.7],
        'DEF_POINT1':[1,7,8,9],
        'DEF_POINT2':[np.nan,2,3,4],
        'DEF_POINT3':[np.nan,np.nan,10,15],
        'DEF_POINT4':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Since I am new to pandas and python I do not know how to write a function/Loop to perform above task without hard coding it?
Please help...

Comment: If you multiple by NaN you get a NaN back... so does /`df.filter(like='DEF_').mul(df.PRO_RATE, axis=0)` might do what you're after...?

Comment: @JonClements I like that!  However, the OP isn't multiplying across the rows.  It appears each column is being shifted down by the number of `NaN` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Given the `DataFrame` provided in the question:

```
for column in df.columns[2:]:
    isnull_count = (df[column].isnull().sum())
    calc_values = df.PRO_RATE * df[x].shift(-isnull_count)
    calc_values = calc_values.dropna().tolist()  # optional line
    calc_values = [round(x, 2) for x in calc_values]  # optional line
    print(f'{x}: {calc_values}')
```

#### Output:

```
DEF_POINT2: [1.0, 0.9, 2.4]
DEF_POINT3: [5.0, 4.5]
DEF_POINT4: [10.0]
```